# Is LIBSVM thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, multicore, libsvm

I would like to take advantage of today's CPU mutli-core capabilities when using LIBSVM. What I'd like to know/understand is whether I can safely call LIBSVM services from multiple threads concurrently (e.g., call svm_train() on 8 different models with different parameters for the process of parameter tuning).

The only reference I could find is this one at LIBSVM's site:
[Q: How can I use OpenMP to parallelize LIBSVM on a multicore/shared-memory computer?](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f432)

The thing is that it talks about parallelizing the algorithm (code) of the training function itself, but say nothing about calling the training function concurrently multiple times - which I would prefer since it gives me better control on the cross-validation & parameter-tuning/grid-search process.

Note: I'm using LIBSVM package itself (currently the java implementation and potentially python too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you want to call svm_train() on 8 different problem instances and different parameters to get different model instances!

When I look at the Java-Sourcecode I see that the problem and parameter instances are only read and nothing is written to them. The method creates all objects itself which it needs to modify and store data and finally returns the created model.

That means that calling svm_train() from multiple threads should be no problem.

Comment: Thanks @fatih for inspecting the code - it didn't occur to me doing so myself. I did however test it while mutli-threading and my limited test supports your conclusion.
I guess it'd been best to get a confirmation the library was designed/implemented with concurrency in mind. Multi-threading is a tricky task that if isn't done properly (even when seem legitimate) can easily go under the radar as such.
As I couldn't find any such confirmation, or at least someone with substantial experience using it in multi-threaded environment, the leap of faith in the code is the best one could rely on :-)

Comment: I agree with you. Can you point me to the particular code of the implementation which does not occur to support multithreading?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me - I have no claims that the code or parts of it do not support multi-threading. I couldn't find a confirmation (or even a use case) that LibSvm is multi-threaded by design. Such confirmation would have (hopefully) guaranteed that the library: 1) was tested and verified for such usage 2) will remain so in future versions - issues which can not be guaranteed by code review. Having said that, knowing the code presents no concurrency violations (thanks to your efforts) definitely re-assures when using it in such a manner.

Comment: Yes, it looks like I misunderstood you :) Thank you for your explanation. Especially point 2 is really very important.

Comment: Fatih however i am having problem. It seems like not thread safe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136650/libsvm-attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-this-is-often-an-indicatio

Comment: We never talked about the original C implementation or the C# wrapper. It is possible that they may not be thread safe. Never worked with them.